# Formal single word instead of meeting

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a very formal word instead of meeting.
This is a small meeting with less than 20 people to discuss the current regulations in industry. It will be used for our huge conference this year as one of small sessions in the event.
Do you know any formal word for it?
I thought of meeting, talk and conference, but my boss does not like them.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Avoid word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: For example, one of the things the question will need to clarify is exactly what your boss's criteria are. Without this information, our experts don't know which answers will be useful, and the question becomes a mind-reading game.  See: “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)”.

Comment: @MetaEd  Um I don’t know her criteria. She just asked me to collect some formal words so that she can choose one.

Comment: @ArchieAzares Avoid answers in comments. We get it: standards for comments are low, they get an undeserved privileged position on the page above answers, and they cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. But this discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: [Privileges > Comment Everywhere – Help Center](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). See also: [Is SE enforcing “no answers in comments”? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10646/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your specific scenario of naming smaller meetings that are part of a bigger conference, then I think the phrase you are looking for is [breakout session](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/breakout-session.html).

> Relatively short session where a small group of attendees, drawn from a large conference or convention, discusses specific subjects or aspects of the broad theme of the main gathering. Also called a breakout meeting.

Read more: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/breakout-session.html